# How to Remove Key Bindings

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have a standard command registered in the *plugin.xml* with a handler and key bindings like this:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <scheme
        id="AcmeSchema"
        name="ACME Schema">
  </scheme>
  <key
        commandId="org.acme.module.myCommand"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow"
        schemeId="AcmeSchema"
        sequence="M1+M2+M3+F6">
  </key>
</extension>
```

Everything works fine and the key binding is shown via `IBindingService#openKeyAssistDialog`.

Now I want to disable the command. (I do that by adding an `activeWhen` to the corresponding handler.) Yet the key binding is still shown. I tried hiding the command via activity, but it's still shown. The key binding itself does not have a `visibleWhen` or something similar.

The problem here is that even though the command is not visible anywhere, it can still be triggered via the shortcut key. And since the internal rules for its enablement are not fullfilled, executing the command fails.

How do I remove a key binding for a command that is no longer active?